# Play framework WS url spaces

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a problem calling WS.url() in play framework 2.3.3 with url containing spaces. All other characters all url encoded automatically but not spaces. When i try to change all spaces to "%20", WS convert it to "%2520" because of "%" character. With spaces i've got java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query. How can i handle this ?

part of the URL's query String:

```
 &input=/mnt/mp3/music/folder/01 - 23.mp3
```

The code looks like this:

```
Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise = WS.url(url).setAuth("", "cube", WSAuthScheme.BASIC).get().map(
                new Function<WSResponse, JsonNode>() {
                    public JsonNode apply(WSResponse response) {
                        System.out.println(response.getBody());
                        JsonNode json = response.asJson();
                        return json;
                    }
                }
                );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should "build" your URL based on the way java.net.URL(which Play! uses for it's WS) does it. WS.url() follows the same logic.

The use of URLEncoder/Decoder is recommended only for form data. 
From JavaDoc:

> "Note, the java.net.URI class does perform escaping of its component
>   fields in certain circumstances. The   recommended way to manage the
>   encoding and decoding of URLs is to use java.net.URI, and to convert
>   between these two classes using toURI() and URI.toURL().  The
>   URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for HTML
>   form encoding, which is not   the same as the encoding scheme defined
>   in RFC2396."

So, the solution is to use **THIS**:

```
WS.url(baseURL).setQueryString(yourQueryString);
```

Where:

1. `baseURL` is your scheme + host + path etc.
2. `yourQueryString` is... well, your query String, but **WITHOUT** the `?`: input=/mnt/mp3/music/folder/01 - 23.mp3

Or, if you want to use a more flexible, programmatic approach, **THIS**:

```
WS.url(baseURL).setQueryParameter(param, value);
```

Where:

1. `param` is the parameter's name in the query String
2. `value` is the value of the parameter

If you want multiple parameters with values in your query you need to chain them by adding another `.setQueryParameter(...)`. This implies that this approach is not very accomodating for complex, multi-parameter query Strings.

Cheers!

Comment: That works great. I was missing setQueryString method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the console you will find that the exception is : `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index ...`

That's because play Java api uses `java.net.URL` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-ws/src/main/java/play/libs/ws/ning/NingWSRequestHolder.java) in line 47).

You can use java.net.URLEncoder to encode your URL

```
WS.url("http://" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("google.com/test me", "UTF-8"))
```

**UPDATE**

If you want an RFC 2396 compliant method you can do this :

```
java.net.URI u = new java.net.URI(null, null, "http://google.com/test me",null);
System.out.println("encoded url " + u.toASCIIString());
```

Comment: Not recommended to use URLEncoder/Decoder. From JavaDocs: "The URLEncoder and URLDecoder classes can also be used, but only for HTML form encoding, which is not the same as the encoding scheme defined in RFC2396."

Comment: Careful. The Example you provided with URI(null,null,"http://google.com/test me") applies to the URI constructor URI(String scheme, String ssp, String fragment). That means that the resulted url will look like this(notice the #) ->  #http://google.com/test%20me

Comment: Not really. Altough the printed result is ok the usage of the constructor is not. Correct usage for your case(still not the solution to the OPs problem): URI("http", "google.com", "/test me",null);