# Play framework Ws: how create request without encode?

Tags: scala, http, playframework, playframework-2.3

In this moment, I do integration of our project on Play framework and gis service.

Gis service works with http get queries.

Here the right example of get point request:

```
http://myGisServer.ru/myservice?token=XYZ%3D&query=[{"id":"123","objectIds":["5"]}]
```

Where token is token form auth service, and this must be encoded for http request.
And query is not encoded json with specified parameters.

I create this request with ws:

```
def getPoint = Action.async{
  val data = Json.obj(
      "id" -> "123",
      "objectIds" -> Json.arr("5")
  )
  val ws = WS.url("http://myGisServer.ru/myservice").withQueryString(
    "token" -> currentToken,
    "query" -> data.toString()
  )
  val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = ws.get()
  futureResponse.map(response => {
    Ok(response.json)
  })
}
```

But that doesn't work because ws encode all request, including json string.
How can I exclude json from encoding, or create other query without encoding?

Comment: What happens if you use `WS.url("http://myGisServer.ru/myservice?token=XYZ%3D&query=[{\"id\":\"123\",\"objectIds\":[\"5\"]}]").get()`?

Comment: @Salem Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index ...

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340400/play-framework-ws-url-spaces)? Seems to be relevant to your case. Which version of play are you using? Specifically which version of `ning` client?